# Is it a bad practice to keep strong ui related state inside of the react component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, mobx

I am migrating my reactJs app to redux/mobx.
For now I have 3 components, each of them have, in their state, the following structure:

```
name:string,
surname:string,
showError: boolean,
loading:boolean
```

As you can see it can make sense to move name/surname to a centralized repository so to maintain a global state. 
I'm not so sure about showError and loading: they are booleans meant to show an error message and a spinner inside of the specific component.

I personally don't like the idea of putting such "UI-related state" in the centralized state, I'd like to make it stay inside of the specific component as other components will never have the need to access/update such things.

So my idea is the following:

```
this.state = {showError, loading};
this.businessState = props.state;
```

In short I will continue updating the "state" with the React's setState() function, while leaving to redux/mobx the management of the so called "business state".

Can this be a good practice or I am doing something particularily bad?

Comment: If you can't benefit from having UI state in global state, it likely belongs to local state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd suggest making `store` for most `components` and from my experience most of the `stores` actually are `ViewStore's`. If you have similar logic like `loading` and `errors` on multiple `components` then it's even easier with doing something like this:

```
class BaseViewStore {
    @observable loading = false
    @observable showError = false
}
```

Then your `component store` would just extend this `store` and you'd have reusable logic within this `base store`. Everything that is `component` specific would go in that specific `store` of course. That way your `components` would be clean, have no `personal state` (within `component` itself) and could be easily replaced with other components since your behaviour (state) would be in the `stores`.

Answer (score 1):

I personally have no problem with this as 'loading' and 'showError' relate to the state not the UI component. It is basically saying, when I populate my state from an API call, is it done yet and did anything go wrong? The UI component displays accordingly.

I would make showError a string or string[] depending on the structure of the errors thrown from your BE system.

I would also break your state into specific reducers that deal specific business functions and load states based on the specific business functions and not load per component on the page.

I hope that helps in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if It's a best practice or not. But the loading state is used when you do some async action like get data from API. The best practice for getting data like that is doing via action. And what I usually do inside the action is to dispatch a loading state before call the API, and dispatch a reducer which set loading to false after got the data.

So, in my opinion. I would store loading state inside redux instead of using component state.

It would be something like this

action.js

```
getData = () => {
   return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({ type: LOADING });
      callApiToGetData()
         .then(data => {
            dispatch({ type: SUCCESS, data })
         })
         .catch(e => {
            dispatch({ type: ERROR, error: e })
         })
   }
}
```

reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  data: null,
  loading: false,
  error: null
}

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOADING:
       return { ...state, loading: true }
    case SUCCESS:
       return { ...state, loading: false, data: action.data, error: null }  
    case FAIL:
       return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.error }
    default:  
       return state
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use async/await inside of reducers? Or am I forced with that snippet with promises? I ask because for now I am using mobx and I'm not very expert about redux

Comment: It's possible to use async/await in action (not reducer. reducer is just for mapping data after business logic from action). Just make sure you use the version of babel and ecmascript you are using supports it.

Comment: just to be added. You need to use redux-thunk to make it possible to do such asynchronous actions.